# create empty workbook in memory openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
book = Workbook()
for country in "IN US JP UK".split():
    book.create_sheet(title=country)
```

This creates 5 sheets with the first sheet being unwanted.

I know that I can do this:

```
book = Workbook()
us_ws = book.active
us_ws.title = "IN"
for country in "US JP UK".split():
    book.create_sheet(title=country)
```

Is there any short cut?

Comment: What do you want a *shortcut* for? You could always use a `WriteOnlyWorksheet`.

Comment: shortcut for not adding unwanted sheet added with Workbook() method. Thanks for pointing out writeonlyworksheet

Comment: This is what I was looking for @CharlieClark. Thanks. Please add it as answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the ([Docs](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#create-a-workbook))

> A workbook is always created with at least one worksheet. You can get it by using the openpyxl.workbook.Workbook.active() property

So if you do not need the default sheet, you can delete it:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook()
book.remove(book.active)
for country in "IN US JP UK".split():
    book.create_sheet(title=country)
```

This deletes the first sheet, which will be the default created sheet, before creating the desired sheets.

Or, as pointed out in comments, if you are OK with the caveats of a write-only workbook you can do:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook(write_only=True)
for country  in "IN US JP UK".split():
    book.create_sheet(title=country )
```

Comment: Workbooks without at least one worksheet are invalid files.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Please add it as answer and I will delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution as per suggestions from @CharlieClark

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook(write_only=True)
for cc in "IN US JP UK".split():
    book.create_sheet(title=cc)
```